# Referring to one column in range defined by a table

Tags: excel, range, vba

How do I refer to a single column in a range that is defined by a table?

```
Dim LandscapingDataRange As Range
Set LandscapingDataRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet6.Name).ListObjects("TableReportLandscaping").DataBodyRange

LandscapingSiteMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ContactListRange(MailCounter, 3), LandscapingDataRange(3), 0
```

I would like to refer to the third column only in the LandscapingDataRange, however above refers to only one cell.

Comment: The `Listobject` object has a `ListColumns` property.

Comment: Yes, but lets say I use the LandscapingDataRange several times, and each time I need to refer to a different column only. Is that possible without having to define separate ranges for each listcolumns?

Comment: Yes - just change the index you pass to `ListColumns`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you will need to specify with an example. I'm not that well known with VBA.

Comment: `LandscapingSiteMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ContactListRange(MailCounter, 3), LandscapingDataRange.Listcolumns(3).Range, 0)` If you don't want to include headers, use `DataBodyRange` rather than `Range`

Comment: Doesn't work: <Object doesn't support this property or method>. Does it have anything to do with `LandscapingDataRange` already referring to a `databodyrange`?

Comment: Yes - sorry misread. In that case you can either just use: `LandscapingDataRange.columns(3)` or assign the `Listobject` to `LandscapingDataRange` and use the syntax I showed.

Answer (score 0):

With much of my programming, I try very hard not to confuse myself :) So I typically initialize a set of "standard" objects to provide the access I need. Depending on how often the data and columns in the table may change, I sometimes choose to access the columns by name, rather than by number.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tblLandscaping As ListObject
    Dim tblLandscapingDBR As Range
    Dim tblLandscapingDataCol As Range
    Dim colName As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set tblLandscaping = ws.ListObjects("TableReportLandscaping")
    Set tblLandscapingDBR = tblLandscaping.DataBodyRange
    Debug.Print "address range of DataBodyRange      = " & tblLandscapingDBR.Address & _
                " num rows = " & tblLandscapingDBR.Rows.Count & _
                " cols = " & tblLandscapingDBR.Columns.Count
    Set tblLandscapingDataCol = tblLandscaping.ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange
    Debug.Print "address range of column 3           = " & tblLandscapingDataCol.Address & _
                " num rows = " & tblLandscapingDataCol.Rows.Count

    colName = tblLandscaping.Name & "[Contracts]"
    Set tblLandscapingDataCol = ws.Range(colName)
    Debug.Print "address range of column 'Contracts' = " & tblLandscapingDataCol.Address & _
                " num rows = " & tblLandscapingDataCol.Rows.Count
End Sub
```